# Symfony FOSOAuthServerBundle: access token not detected

Tags: symfony, oauth, fosoauthserverbundle

I'm using FOSOAuthServerBundle as my oauth endpoint. I succesfully generated a token using the `Resource Owner Password Credentials` grant method:

```
{
    "access_token": "MY-FOO-TOKEN",
    "expires_in": ​3600,
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "scope": "read",
    "refresh_token": "MY-BAR-REFRESH-TOKEN"
}
```

Now I would like to use it to get some protected resources. So I did:

```
curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer MY-FOO-TOKEN" "http://localhost:8000/api/a-bar-resource"
```

The Bearer do not seem to be detected.

---

INFOS:

`echo $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken();` gives:
`AnonymousToken(user="anon.", authenticated=true, roles="")`

In the headers there is:

```
["authorization"]=> /** <-- Is the lowercase OK? **/
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(93) "Bearer MY-FOO-TOKEN"
  }
```

I also tried to pass `access_token` as a query parameter, without success.

Now I'm guessing something is wrong with the `config.yml` or the `security.yml`. Here are some selected parts:

config.yml:

```
fos_oauth_server:
[...]
    service:
        options:
            supported_scopes: read
        user_provider: fos_user.user_provider.username_email
```

security.yml:

```
security:
[...]
    firewalls:
        api:
            pattern:    ^/api
            fos_oauth:  true
            stateless:  true
            anonymous:  false
    access_control:
            - { path: ^/api, roles: [ IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY ] }
```

Comment: Advice I got: "I think you have to debug it from the vendor source `oAuthProvider` class in `Security\Authentication\Provider`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found what was causing the problem. I had a firewall that was nullifying the other firewall, because of same patterns:

```
security:
[...]
    firewalls:
        other_firewall: #this one
            pattern:    ^/
            anonymous:  true
        api:
            pattern:    ^/api
            fos_oauth:  true
            stateless:  true
            anonymous:  true
```

I also think that an authentication made in one firewall is not available in an other firewall, so diminishing the number of firewalls to the strict minimum (one not secured, one with auth etc.) is a good practice. Then using `access_control` for fine access.

Comment: Same error and handle it by inversing the order of patterns : start with ^/api and end with ^/.